# 'webstorm.typescript.webpack_alias'. I can't get smart tips when i use alias in tsx

Tags: typescript, webpack, webstorm, alias, tsconfig

1.I built a project through the create-reaction-app (typescript).

2.Then, I run eject.

3. I set The webstorm : Language&Frameworks > Javascript > webpack, to a webpack config.

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: '', 
    output: {},
    module: {},
    resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', 'config.js', '.json'],
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/'),
        },
    },
};
```

4. tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "extends": "./paths"
}
```

this is the  ./paths file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["*"]
    }
  }
}
```

When I use '@' to instead absolute path like '../../' in .js file, it works well, but fail in the jsx file. (I mean the project will compile successfully，but webstorm cant prompt me for the code)

Did I set something wrong? How can I get the smart tips?

Answer (score 0):

In Typescript projects, path aliases in webpack configuration file are not used for path resolving, path mappings from `tsconfig.json` are used instead. But the IDE won't treat `paths` file as a valid `tsconfig.json` and thus won't read mappings from it. You need to either rename your file or add its name to a list of patterns registered for **TypeScript Config** file type in **Settings | Editor | File Types**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And I have solved the problem,just wrote it up~~~

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved the problem.

First I rewrite the "./paths".(or you can actually merge it into tsconfig.json)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVbbz.png)

when you insert '/' after @,you will get the smart tips...